# Show Websites with their own icons in the windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, taskbar

I want to add some websites to my taskbar and run them in their very own (chrome) instances with their icons.

I tried to create a short cut on my desktop and move it to the taskbar, but this adds only a "pinned entry" to my chrome icon. But I want an own icon (for example Netflix).

Comment: Google Chrome "Create Application" shortcut.

Comment: Related: [Make Google Chrome “Application” Windows Use High-Quality Icons in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/16827/make-google-chrome-application-windows-use-high-quality-icons-in-windows-7)